# What does the 'rows' specification do in intersect(tableA,tableB,'rows')

Tags: matlab-table

I read the documentation upside-down and sideways.  For the life of me, I can't discern what the effect of 'rows' is.  Here is my test code, which also doesn't seem to be revealing.

```
>> a=table((1:5)',{'a';'bc';'def';'gh';'i'})
   a = Var1    Var2
       ____    _____
       1       'a'
       2       'bc'
       3       'def'
       4       'gh'
       5       'i'

>> b=a([1 2 3],:)
   b = Var1    Var2
       ____    _____
       1       'a'
       2       'bc'
       3       'def'

>> c=a([2 3 4],:)
   c = Var1    Var2
       ____    _____
       2       'bc'
       3       'def'
       4       'gh'

>> intersect(b,c)
   ans = Var1    Var2
         ____    _____
         2       'bc'
         3       'def'

>> intersect(b,c,'rows')
   ans = Var1    Var2
         ____    _____
         2       'bc'
         3       'def'
```

Thanks to anyone who can provide clarity on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing. If the inputs `A` and `B` are tables with the same variables, we have:

> Two rows that have the same values, but different names, are considered equal.

Thus, the `'rows'` option is included by default. In fact, the underlying call to `intersect` in the table `intersect` method (@table\intersect.m) is:

```
[~,ia,ib] = intersect(ainds,binds,flag,'rows');
```

It is only necessary to use it to distinguish the intersect of elements of an array or rows of array. E.g.

```
A = [2 2 2; 0 0 1; 1 2 3; 1 1 1];
B = [1 2 3; 2 2 2; 2 2 0];

>> [C, ia, ib] = intersect(A,B)

C =

     0
     1
     2
     3
```

vs

```
>> [C, ia, ib] = intersect(A,B, 'rows')

C =

     1     2     3
     2     2     2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you [read the documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html), for the `intersect(a,b)` form it says:

> If A and B are tables, then intersect returns the set of rows common to both tables.

For the `intersect(a,b,'rows')` form it says:

> treats each row of A and each row of B as single entities and returns the rows common to both A and B.

So, one can conclude that for *tables* the operations are identical, as you have demonstrated. However, if one uses plain old arrays, the behaviour differs:

```
a = randi(10, 10)
intersect(a, a)
ans = 
    1
    2
  ...
   10
```

Here we have flattened the arrays and looked for identical cells.

```
intersect(a, a, 'rows')
ans =
    9  3 ... 7
    ...
```

Here we compare by rows, and get results back as complete matching rows, as if the arrays were tables as you showed in your question.

You can also try:

```
a = randi(10, 10)
b = randi(10, 10)
intersect(a, b)
intersect(a, b, 'rows')
```

And see that you almost always get 1 to 10 for the first form, and almost never get any matches for the second form.

Comment: I was reading the documentation (see my original post).  It sure sounded like it had no effect, but I was convinced that I wasn't interpreting the documentation right because, surely, if the intent was for 'rows' to have no effect, it would have been explicit, even if that was only for tables.  I know that if I was documenting something, that would surely be the expectation of me that I would anticipate.